# Implementing Particle Swarm Optimization

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Hello I'm new to  metaheuristics algorithm. Can anyone help me understand
how to apply the PSO?

Given the function $f(a,b)=a^2+b^2$. How can I find $min f(a,b)=a^2+b^2$ using PSO method with three iterations? I understand the concept of PSO but I had a hard time implementing it. I don't know how to plug info into the algorithm.

Comment: This is a fairly broad question. How are your starting positions chosen? (If a particle starts at $(0,0)$, then you're done.) How many particles do you have? What are the parameters? etc.

Comment: Also, since PSO is a non-deterministic heuristic, you're going to get different results every time, and you can' t expect to find the actual minimum of the function.